# Uialertview text to NSMutableArray, ios 4.3

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, uialertview

i have been trying to copy text input from alertview textfield to a NSMutableArray that i will use later, alertview pops up and i enter the input to text field but when i press OK alert view disappears but doesnt copy text to my mutable array

here is my code

```
-(IBAction)add:(UIButton *)sender
{
    addCustomStand = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter a Stand Location"
                                                     message:@"  "   
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    UITextField *nameField = [[UITextField alloc] 
                              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
    [nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
     nameField.text = @"";
    [dialog addSubview:nameField];

    if ([nameField text]){
        NSLog(@"Name Field %@ ",nameField.text);
        [addCustomStand addObject:nameField.text];
    }

    [nameField release];
    [dialog show];
    [dialog release];   
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");
        NSLog(@"StandLocations %@ ",addCustomStand);
    }
}
```

here is my output on log screen

```
2012-02-07 20:26:57.315 Avicii[1399:b603] Name Field  
2012-02-07 20:26:59.720 Avicii[1399:b603] Button 1 was selected.
2012-02-07 20:26:59.721 Avicii[1399:b603] StandLocations (
    ""
)
```

anyone can help whats wrong with that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `[nameField text]` doesn't have user entered value yet when you added it in your `[addCustomStand addObject:nameField.text];`

so change your adding into array in `UIAlertView` delegate method.

```
-(IBAction)add:(UIButton *)sender
{
    addCustomStand = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter a Stand Location"
                                                     message:@"  "   
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    UITextField *nameField = [[UITextField alloc] 
                              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
    [nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    nameField.text = @"";
    // Note at this line
    nameField.tag = 100; 
    //
    [dialog addSubview:nameField];

    [nameField release];
    [dialog show];
    [dialog release];   
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {
        // Note at this line
        UITextField* nameField = (UITextField *)[alertView viewWithTag:100];
        [addCustomStand addObject:nameField.text];
        //
        NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");
        NSLog(@"StandLocations %@ ",addCustomStand);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for help that works and what does nameField.tag = 100; line do there?

Comment: that is just giving a tag to your nameField, it could be any number, I just arbitrarily pick 100. What it does is giving your nameField a tag number (100) before you add it to subview. So in your UIAlertView delegate, you can retrieve your nameField there using `[alertView viewWithTag:100]`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `nameField.text` to your addCustomStand array before you even show the alert dialog.  At the time you add it to the array the value is an empty string.

Instead you need to copy the value into your array during your `clickedButtonAtIndex:` method, by doing something like this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {
        NSString *location;
        UIView *view;
        for (view in [alertView subviews]) {

            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                location = [(UITextField*)view text];
            }
        }

        if (location) {
            [addCustomStand addObject:location];
        }
    }
}
```